# SpineJS / Hem + Jade Templates

Tags: pug, spine.js

How do you get Spine/Hem to render Jade templates? In the last line of the [documentation](http://spinejs.com/docs/views_jade) it says you just have to include jade's *runtime.js* as a lib in *slug.json* but when I do that and run my application I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined application.js:46
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Is there more to it or am I just doing something wrong? I used *npm* to install jade so I just added the path in my *slug.json* like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": [
    "es5-shimify", 
    "json2ify", 
    "jqueryify", 
    "spine",
    "spine/lib/local",
    "spine/lib/ajax",
    "spine/lib/route",
    "spine/lib/manager"
  ],
  "libs": ["node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js"]
}
```

**Thanks**

Comment: what version of hem are you using. newer versions of hem have a slug.json that looks different

Comment: ah that could be it, I'm using 0.1.9. will update and try again. How should slug.json be different? Is there any documentation other than at http://spinejs.com/docs/hem? cheers

Comment: I upgraded to 0.3.2 but still have the same problem

Comment: check out the readme at https://github.com/spine/hem 
the slug json is different with hem 0.3, and it looks like the docs on spinejs.com are out of sync with that. I will try to get those updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are on 0.3 version of hem or newer as jade support wasn't implemented before then then in addition to the up-todate hem docs at github.com/spine/hem checkout the slug.json for a simple example app I did that uses jade and hem

https://github.com/aeischeid/randomizable-excercise-picker/blob/b1c17e10ca1f3dd6e15d5127f1a9d029616f195d/slug.json